# Format a Req.query string to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, req.query

I have a req.query from a get request

```
get <host>/api/tree/path-search?tree="{1:{2:{4:null,5:null},3:null}}"
```

How i convert it to this form in javaScript

```
const obj = { 1 : { 2 : { 4 : null, 5 : null },3 : null}};
```

is the const obj a JavaScript Object

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: when i res.send(obj) the  output format is a json object but when i res.send(req.query.tree) the output format is a string. i want to convert req.query string to a json object

Comment: It _is_ a string. If you want it parsed, did you try parsing it?

Comment: i parsed but the output is again a string

Comment: So give a [mre] _of that_, what exactly did you do?

Comment: @dimitristrakos - *"when i res.send(obj) the output format is a json object"* No, it's just an object, not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I'd **strongly** suggest changing what you put in `tree` to [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) so you can use the built-in JSON parser (`JSON.parse`). The URI might look like this:

```
get <host>/api/tree/path-search?tree=%7B%221%22%3A%7B%222%22%3A%7B%224%22%3Anull%2C%225%22%3Anull%7D%2C%223%22%3Anull%7D%7D
```

...where that value for `tree` is the URI-encoded version of

```json
{"1":{"2":{"4":null,"5":null},"3":null}}
```

Which is valid JSON that parses to what you want.

---

What you have now is a valid JavaScript object literal, but not valid JSON. That means you *could* evaluate it with something that evaluates (executes) JavaScript code like `eval` or `new Function`, but **that executes arbitrary code**, which **you don't want to do on a server**.

Alternatively, parse it with a JavaScript parser. There are several available for the Node.js environment. Then you'd walk through the resulting AST tree building the described object. Which is obviously a pain, which is why I'd use JSON. :-)

Comment: Can somehow convert the tree query in the format that you suggest?

Comment: @dimitristrakos - To do that, you'd have to parse it anyway (e.g., with a JavaScript parser), and once you've done that you may as well use the result directly.